# How to change circle color in progress dialog? (no style.xml, only themes.xml)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressdialog

Hellow, i want to ask something. How can i change this color of circle from Progress Dialog? My project don't have style.xml, it has themes.xml and the dark version of themes.xml so no colorAccent, even so i added colorAccent in themes.xml anyway. I also already changed my secondary and primary color that indicate the same color of this circle but it still didn't change.

[image]

Here is how i make my progress dialog after init:

```
mLoginProgress.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.loginloadingtitle));
mLoginProgress.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.loginloadingmessage));
mLoginProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
mLoginProgress.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `ProgessBar` and set it in `ProgressDialog` using `setIndeterminateDrawable`.

```
ProgressDialog mLoginProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
mLoginProgress.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.loginloadingtitle));
mLoginProgress.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.loginloadingmessage));
mLoginProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
Drawable drawable = new ProgressBar(this).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate();
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
mLoginProgress.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);

mLoginProgress.show();
```

Comment: sorry but i don't use progressbar?

Comment: It's not the  progress bar present in code , I have founded the recourse id of progress bar present inside the progress dialog  `mLoginProgress.findViewById`

Comment: ah i see, so it's like setting the default circle with custom progress bar? then how can i added my own color from colors.xml?

Comment: Yes it's setting your own color in default progress bar , For color change it's the next line `.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#C60000")` , change color in parse color as per required color you want

Comment: ok i'll try it after i fix my emulator again

Comment: it has error say  ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()' on a null object reference```

Comment: @DiooB , I have updated the code a bit , instead of finding the  `progress bar` from `progress dialog` , I created a new `progress bar` and set it in `progress dialog`. This say it seems less crash resistant to me.

Comment: alright now the codes work just like i wanted, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try with
[`ProgressDialog(Context context, int theme)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog#ProgressDialog(android.content.Context,%20int)) with the theme where you added `colorAccent`